# Is CSRF needed on a page that does not have authentication

Tags: csrf

I'm making a configuration page for an embedded Linux device. When the user presses a button, the device starts a WiFi access point. The user connects to the AP and visits the web page. This page is not protected by a password. Anyone who can connect to the AP can visit the page and make any changes. Is CSRF needed here? Can CSRF protection even be added?

Comment: CSRF is fundamentally about abusing somebody else's *authorization* to make changes, not about *authentication*. In this case, the ability to connect to the access point is the authorization. As such, an attacker can absolutely exploit your authorization (without needing to be in WiFi range of you) via CSRF. Mind you, since WiFi range is usually significant, you probably should have some additional security control beyond "in range" before authorizing users to make changes, but that's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @CBHacking What about login CSRF? No ambient authority needed for that.

Comment: Fair point @jub0bs but very few sites even try to protect against that, most have no need to (e.g. what would be the point of doing it on StackExchange? You get the rep for posts I make before I notice that the username is wrong or I have the wrong number next to the username?), and it's hard to _securely_ protect against it anyhow (needing the ability to plant a cookie or similar adds a substantial speedbump, but if the attacker can do that or similar, they can probably bypass any login CSRF protection you might create).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Yes, you do.

The problem with CSRF is that it essentially allows an attacker to send requests to a site he can't directly access. That means, an attacker could create a page, which causes the victim to send an unwanted POST request to the configuration page, essentially changing the configuration. The fact that you don't require authentication is irrelevant.

Example scenario: your laptop is both connected to the internet (say via wired network) and to the device's wifi. In your browser you have two tabs open: the device's admin page, and `mechsawesomeblog.net`. Normally the device is not visible from the internet, but without CSRF protection, the javascript in the `mechsawesomeblog.net` tab can send POSTs to your device and change its config.

#### How to protect against CSRF attacks?

The simplest way is the "Double Submit Cookie Pattern". Essentially, when the user requests the page, you create a nonce (a value which needs to be random and hard to guess), which you send both as a cookie and in a hidden field in the form.

When the client loads the page and submits a legitimate configuration change, the nonce is returned both as cookie and in the hidden field. Since both values are identical, the request is seen as legitimate. If the values mismatch or are not legitimate, the request is ignored.

#### How does this protect against CSRF attacks?

An attacker can only cause the user to submit POST requests from the browser of the victim. This means that if the victim has never visited the configuration page, there is no cookie to be sent, and as such, the request will always fail.

If the victim has a CSRF cookie, the body of the POST request needs to contain the *same* value as is stored in the cookie. However, the attacker does not know the correct value, and attempting to brute-force it should be infeasible.

#### How exploitable is this?

In all honesty, I would rate it as *unlikely, but possible*. First of all, given that it's an IoT device, it will likely be reachable via IP address. And while the number of *plausible* addresses is not as big, it still makes the attack more difficult.

Secondly, the severity of the attack depends on the configuration. Adding new users able to connect via SSH will be more critical, whereas changing the color of an LED will be less critical.

#### tl;dr

Use the [Double Submit Cookie Pattern](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#double-submit-cookie) and you will be fine.

Comment: +1 I thought "This could really use an example", so I added one. I hope that's helpful. Feel free to revert, I won't be offended.

Comment: cant an attacker use Javascript to make a GET request in order to get the cookie?

Comment: @314332906 No, they cannot. The cookie is only ever submitted to the domain the cookie belongs to, never any third party. If this was possible, then that would mean any website, which uses cookies for session management would be trivial to have their session cookies stolen.

Comment: 1) So, I guess what was being said here is that if the victim gets a cookie, then the attacker could never actually see or modify that cookie but would have to know the token in advance to be able have it match when submitting a POST request?

Comment: 2) And this also means the cookie is stored in the browser and this heavily relies on the browser working properly and not leaking the cookie right?

Comment: @MikeOunsworth Thanks, without this example, this still would have made no sense to me. So, basically, this is an issue that can only happen if an attacker has a website/app that a victim has open while connected to their network where they're authorized to access some server?

Answer (score -3):

You do not need it, unless you add auth

Comment: That's true for services that are intended to be publicly-accessible on the internet. Not true for local devices or backend services, as MechMK1's answer points out.